# Where does code Execution start in a child process?

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

Consider the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* main --- do the work */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t child;

    if ((child = fork()) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: fork of child failed: %s\n",
            argv[0], strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    } else if (child == 0) {
                    // do something in child
            }
    } else {
    // do something in parent
    }
}
```

My question is from where does in the code the child process starts executing, i.e. which line is executed first??
If it executes the whole code, it will also create its own child process and thing will go on happening continuously which does not happen for sure!!!

If it starts after the fork() command, how does it goes in if statement at first??

Comment: "which does not happen for sure!!!" So just to be clear you've run this, and it only forked once?

Comment: Well: the fork() call returns **twice**: once for the parent, and once for the child. For the moment, parent and child only differ in the returnvalue from the fork.

Answer (score 8):

It starts the execution of the child in the return of the fork function. Not in the start of the code. The fork returns the pid of the child in the parent process, and return 0 in the child process.

Answer (score 7):

When you execute a `fork()` the thread is duplicated into memory.

So what effectively happens is that you will have two threads that executes the snippet you posted but their `fork()` return values will be different.

For the child thread `fork()` will return 0, so the other branch of the `if` won't be executed, same thing happens for the father thread.

When `fork()` is called the operating system assigns a new address space to the new thread that is going to spawn, then starts it, they will both share the same code segment but since the return value will be different they'll execute different parts of the code (if correctly split, like in your example)

Answer (score 2):

The child starts by executing the next instruction (not line) after fork. So in your case it is the assignment of the fork's return value to the child variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if i understand your question correctly, i can say to you that your code will run as a process already.When you run a code,it is already a process , so that this process goes if statement anyway. After fork(), you will have another process(child process).

In Unix, a process can create another process, that's why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Code execution in a child process starts from the next instruction following the `fork()` system call.

`fork()` system call just creates a seperate address space for the child process therefore it is a cloned copy of the parent process and the **child process has all the memory elements of it's parent's process**.

Thus, after spawning a child process through fork(), both processes (the parent process and the child process) ***resumes the execution right from the next instruction following the `fork()` system call***.